# Banach Spaces: Pointwise Limit vs. Uniform Limit

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

**Agreement**

All notions are up to null sets.

Limits are meant by simple functions.

**Problem**

Given a finite measure space $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ and a Banach space $E$.

Consider bounded measurable functions $F:\Omega\to E: \|F\|_\infty<\infty$.

Precisely the pointwise limits have separable image:
$$S_n\stackrel{0}{\to}F\iff \mathrm{im}F\text{ separable}$$
and precisely the uniform limits have precompact image:
$$S_n\stackrel{\infty}{\to}F\iff \mathrm{im}F\text{ precompact}$$
*(Is it right like this?)*

Now, what is an example of a pointwise limit but not a uniform limit?
$$S_n\stackrel{0}{\to}F,\,S'_n\stackrel{\infty}{\nrightarrow}F$$

Note that the special ingredients are: Finite Measure + Bounded & Measurable Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And again a variant of the famous example:
$$F:(0,1]\to\mathcal{H}:F(\frac{1}{n+1}<t\leq\frac{1}{n}):=e_n$$
Clearly, it is pointwise limit but can't be uniform limit.

Comment: Do you mean $L^2$? $\ell^2$ usually denotes the square summable sequence space. Also here the pointwise limit is not actually in $L^2$.

Comment: @Ian: I really meant $\ell^2$. Can you explain your doubts? Let me think about it, too.

Comment: @Ian: Ok, any infinite dimensional Hilbert space would do the job. The key fact is that orthonormal vectors have distance two.

Comment: I suppose I didn't understand what you meant by $\chi_{1/n}$. I assumed from context that you meant $\chi_{[0,1/n]}$.

Comment: And funnily, I thought so too. But I meant orthonormal elements.