# Bochner Integral vs. Riemann Integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record. See: [Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Anyway, it is written as problem. Have fun! :)

**Reference**

This thread is directly related to:

- [Bochner Integral: Axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1042887/79762)
- [Bochner Integral: Integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1042909/79762)
- [Riemann Integral: Bounded Nonexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1021482/79762)
- [Riemann Integral: Uniform Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041475/79762)
- [Riemann Integral: Improper Version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1039802/79762)
- [Riemann Integral vs. Uniform Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1017558/79762)

and it is indirectly related to:

- [Stone's Theorem Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038782/79762)
- [Nonmeasurable Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1032704/79762)
- [Pointwise Limit vs. Uniform Limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041563/79762)

**Prologue**

This is the final comparison.

All notions are up to null sets.

**Definitions**

Given a finite measure space $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ and a Banach space $E$.

Consider plain functions $F:\Omega\to E$.

Denote the Bochner measurable functions by $\mathcal{B}$.

Define the Bochner integral by:
$$F\in\mathcal{B}:\quad\int F\mathrm{d}\mu:=\lim_n\int S_n\mathrm{d}\mu$$
for simple functions satisfying:
$$\int\|F-S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\to0$$
Denote the Bochner integrable functions by $\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{B}$.

Define the generalized Riemann integral by:
$$\int_\mathfrak{R}F\mathrm{d}\mu:=\lim_\mathcal{P}\{\sum_{a\in A\in\mathcal{P}}F(a)\mu(A)\}_\mathcal{P}$$
over finite measurable partitions:
$$\mathcal{P}\subseteq\Sigma:\quad\Omega=\bigsqcup_{A\in\mathcal{P}}A\quad(\#\mathcal{P}<\infty)$$
being ordered by refinement:
$$\mathcal{P}\leq\mathcal{P}':\iff\forall A'\in\mathcal{P}'\exists A\in\mathcal{P}:\quad A\supseteq A'$$
Denote Riemann integrable functions by $\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R}$.

**Problem**

Clearly, boundedness is a necessary condition for Riemann integrability:
$$f:(0,1]\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}:\quad f\in\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{B},\,f\notin\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R}$$

However, there are also bounded Riemann integrable functions that are not Bochner integrable:
$$F:[0,1]\to\ell^2[0,1]:t\mapsto\chi_t:\quad F\notin\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{B},\,F\in\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R}$$

Moreover, both strictly include the uniform integral:
$$\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{U}\subsetneq\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{B}\land\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{U}\subsetneq\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R}$$

> So the remaining question is wether at least for the bounded case:
>   $$\|F\|_\infty<\infty:\quad F\in\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{B}\implies F\in\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R}$$
>   and especially:
>   $$\int_\mathfrak{R}F\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_\mathfrak{B}F\mathrm{d}\mu$$
>   *(Have a guess! ;))*

Comment: I have begun to study some things about integration in banach space but for now I don't know much yet. Can you explain better why the function $t\to \chi_t$ is Riemann integrable but not Bochner ?

Comment: Sure. The function simply fails to be approximable via simple functions: The elements $\chi_t\in\ell^2[0,1]$ for $t\in[0,1]$ define pairwise orthogonal norm one elements and thus span a subspace of uncountable dimension. In particular, there exists no approximation by a *sequence* of functions with finite dimensional ranges like simple functions.

Comment: I don't see why $$t\mapsto\chi_{t}$$ is Riemann integrable. The net (or filter, whatever) is clearly divergent as whatever partition and its refinement you choose, the difference of Riemann sums is almost never small, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof**

Consider a bounded function $\|F\|_\infty<\infty$.

Now, by measurability there exists a simple approximation:
$$S_n\in\mathcal{S}:\quad\|F-S_n\|\to0$$
After cutoff and reset it can be chosen to be bounded and decreasing:
$$\|S_n\|\leq2\|F\|:\quad\|F-S_n\|\downarrow0$$
Next, denote sufficiently close points by:
$$\Omega_n:=\{\|F-S_n\|<\varepsilon\}$$
These are increasing so by continuity from above:
$$\mu(\Omega)<\infty:\quad\mu(\Omega_n^\complement)\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0$$
Finally, choose a partition where simple functions are constant:
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^KS_k\chi(A_k):\quad\mathcal{P}_n:=\{A_1,\ldots,A_K\}$$

Putting all together one obtains the estimate:
$$0\leq\|\sum_{\mathcal{P}}F(a)\mu(A)-\sum_{\mathcal{P}'}F(a')\mu(A')\|\leq\left(\|F-S_N\|_{\Omega_N}\mu(\Omega_N)+\|F-S_N\|_{\Omega_N^\complement}\mu(\Omega_N^\complement)\right)\\+\|S_N-S_N\|_\infty\mu(\Omega)+\left(\|F-S_N\|_{\Omega_N}\mu(\Omega_N)+\|F-S_N\|_{\Omega_N^\complement}\mu(\Omega_N^\complement)\right)\\\leq2\left(\|F-S_N\|_{\Omega_N}\mu(\Omega)+3\|F\|_\infty\mu(\Omega_N^\complement)\right)+0<\varepsilon\quad\left(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{P}'\geq\mathcal{P}_{N(\varepsilon)}\right)$$
*(I left out maaany details. I hope it is still clear enough.)*

Thus it is also Riemann integrable $F\in\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R}$.

Moreover, one has an upper bound:
$$\int\|F\|\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\|F\|_\infty\mu(\Omega)<\infty$$

Hence it is also Bochner integrable $F\in\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R}$.

Besides, the preceding construction gives:
$$\|\int_\mathfrak{R}F\mathrm{d}\mu-\int S_n\mathrm{d}\mu\|\leq\ldots\leq\|\int_\mathfrak{R}F\mathrm{d}\mu-\sum_{\mathcal{P}(\varepsilon)}F(a)\mu(A)\|\\+\|F-S_n\|_{\Omega_N}\mu(\Omega)+3\|F\|_\infty\mu(\Omega_N^\complement)<\varepsilon\quad(n\geq N(\varepsilon))$$
and therefore the integrals coincide:
$$\int_\mathfrak{R}F\mathrm{d}\mu=\lim_n\int S_n\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_\mathfrak{B}F\mathrm{d}\mu$$

**Remark**

Note that the above shows for finite measures:
$$\|F\|_\infty<\infty:\quad \|F-S_n\|\downarrow0\implies\int S_n\mathrm{d}\mu\to\int_\mathfrak{R}F\mathrm{d}\mu\quad(F\in\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R})$$

Caution that it may be not uniform limit:
$$F:(0,1]\to\mathcal{H}:F(\frac{1}{n+1}<t\leq\frac{1}{n}):=e_n$$